# I am converting a Crystal report to SSRS. I need to align text to prevent wrap and continue in next text box. How to do that?

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, ssrs-tablix

[image]Here is the crystal report pic. How can we achieve same in SSRS.

Comment: Please be specific in what issue you face. This way it looks like you have not check Microsoft documentation and have not learned anything on SSRS yet.

Comment: Text alignment shown in the attached pic is of Crystal reports. I want to achieve same in SSRS report. Is there anyway to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think those can be emulated as merged cells in a table with two detail lines.

[image]

The cell with the CARTONS field is merged with the one to the right of it. The same for the Tag For field that has the STORE values.

Not sure how to get those lines that overlap the text though.